# ngOnChanges never called

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm quite new to angular and I'm having an issue with a directive that doesn't seem to have its `ngOnChanges()` called. What's especially strange is that I have the same setup somewhere else in the project where it's working as expected and I can't for the life of me see what's different/what I'm missing. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I have a `mat-list` that I want to automatically scroll up and down. For this purpose I have a directive like this:

```
import { coerceBooleanProperty } from '@angular/cdk/coercion';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import {
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  Inject,
  Input,
  OnChanges,
  PLATFORM_ID,
  SimpleChanges
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appScrollIntoView]'
})
export class ScrollIntoViewDirective implements OnChanges {
  @Input() appScrollIntoView: boolean | undefined;

  constructor(
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: any,
    private elementRef: ElementRef
  ) { }

  ngOnChanges(simpleChange: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log("ngOnChanges called");
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      if (coerceBooleanProperty(this.appScrollIntoView)) {
        (this.elementRef.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement).scrollIntoView({
          behavior: 'smooth',
          block: 'center'
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I would expect this `ngOnChanges` to be called. This is the parent component that I hooked it up to.

```
<div *ngIf="!isLoaded; then thenSpinner else elseForm"></div>
<ng-template #thenSpinner>
  <div style="text-align:center; margin-top: 30px;">
    <h3>Wird geladen...</h3>
    <mat-progress-spinner mode="determinate" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; "></mat-progress-spinner>
    <mat-spinner style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; "></mat-spinner>
  </div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #elseForm>
  <div style="height: 100%!important; max-height:100%!important; background-color: rgb(242,242,242); overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="width:90%; margin: auto; max-height:100%;">
      <h2 style="text-align:center">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</h2>
      <mat-list style="overflow: auto; height: calc(100vh - 150px)" *ngIf="isLoaded" id="scrollList" class="list" role="list">
        <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of items"
                       style="height: 500px; max-height: 500px;"
                       [appScrollIntoView]="item === selectedItem"
                       role="listitem">
          <app-approaching-vehicle-info-tile-component [vehicle]=item style="height: 500px; max-height: 500px;"></app-approaching-vehicle-info-tile-component>
        </mat-list-item>
      </mat-list>
    </div>

    <!--<div id="backgroundDiv" style="width: 65%; height: 100%; float: right;">
      <app-stock-overview-no-details></app-stock-overview-no-details>
    </div>-->
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

As you can see the `mat-list-items` have `[appScrollIntoView]="item === selectedItem"`. I verified that `selectedItem` is updated in the parent component correctly. Yet the `ngOnChanges` of the directive seems to never be called. I think I'm missing something super obvious but am currently blind to it. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Did you add ScrollIntoViewDirective in the respective module declaration array?

Comment: That was it! No idea how I missed that. Thank you! But why does it not throw an exception of some kind if its missing there? I feel like it should do that... Do you want to post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: you might have NO_ERROR_SCHEMA in you app which would ignore error related to unknown properties in template.

Comment: No I don't. But the original issue is fixed so thanks again!